# How i can disable sorting for Repeater Form?

Tags: forms, backend, octobercms

I created plugin and for one model i using repeater form to versioning some data. My problem is, that by default you can sort repeater forms. Sorting is happens quickly and you lose the correct sequence of the created data.

The easiest way would be to create another field, but that's not very practical.

In the documentation, unfortunately, I find nothing that could help me.

fields.yaml

`state_update:
  label: 'Version date'
  prompt: 'add new date'
  span: auto
  type: repeater
  tab: Dates
  form:
    fields:
    date:
      label: Date
      mode: date
      span: full
      type: datepicker`

Answer (score 1):

Just add Option

> sortable: false

```
state_update:
  label: 'Version date'
  prompt: 'add new date'
  sortable: false              <= like this
  span: auto
  ...
```

It should work.

ref : https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/backend/formwidgets/Repeater.php

if you have any doubt please comment.

Comment: Does not work. Sorting works via drag and drop. Shouldn't it work with Java Script or aJax?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery code below is working for me.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery("table.acf-table td.order").removeClass("order"); });
```